# How do I reduce the slugsize for my program in heroku (python, tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my discord bot to Heroku but my files exceed over 500MB. I tried to put `.slugignore` in my file but that doesn't seem to work. It'd appear to be because of the TensorFlow library that takes up 454MB.

Here's what in my `requirements.txt`:

```
keras-nightly==2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
nltk==3.6.2
numpy==1.19.5
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.5.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.5.0
```

And here's the error message:

```
Compiled slug size: 533M is too large (max is 500M)
```

Comment: A number of your requirements are quite large. The ability to remove libraries from your deploy is dependent on what your app does -- are you using all of those requirements? If so, you can't delete them without replacing the logic somehow.

Comment: Tensorflow alone weighs 454 mb, I don't think heroku is the best option here.

Comment: I'm working on a discord bot that uses machine learning to receive questions and respond with an answer on that specific topic. I'm quite new to ML myself, but I'll revise and figure out which part I don't need. 
If heroku doesn't work, do you have any other suggestions?